# If $|a|=2$ for all $a \in G$, then why is $abab=e$?

Tags: group-theory

I have a proof that uses assumptions:

Let $G$ be group and $|a|=2$ for all $a \in G$, $a≠e$.

Then (let $a,b \in G$) claims that $abab=e$.

Why is this? I only see that must be $a^2=e$ and $b^2=e$, but not $abab=e$.

Comment: Aha, so it's because by group property (closure) the product is also $ab \in G$. Then by assumption $|a|=2$ $\forall a \in G$ it must be that also $|ab|=2$.

Comment: Yes, it's just use the closure propertie, then the result follows

Comment: It also follows that $G$ is commutative because $ a b=e( a b)e=$ $b^2(a b)a^2=$ $b( b a)^2 a= b e a=b a.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $ab\in G$, then $|ab|=2$, follows that $(ab)^2=(ab)(ab)=abab=e$